# Output contents of query to file from within impala-shell

Tags: impala, io-redirection

I am trying to extract some information from a Hive table and when I run a `describe db.tablename` statement within impala-shell, I see that the output is ~2000 lines.

How can I extract this information into a local file without exiting the interactive mode? I could only find references to do it by passing the `-o` parameter when launching `impala-shell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a reference to this in the docs, but this works -

within `impala-shell` we can do

```sql
set output_file=blah.csv;
select * from dbname.table_name limit 1000;
unset output_file;
```